# How can I replace \\server\Share$ to D: using powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to gather a report of long directory paths to provide to each user who has them so that they can use it and make this folders paths short.

How can I replace \\server\Share$ to X: ? I tried the below but nothing changes. I can only get results if I do only one character or one string "\\server" but not the combination "\\server\Share$" can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong.

```
$results= "\\\server\Share$\super\long\directory\path\"
$usershare="\\\server\Share$"
$Results | ForEach-Object { $_.FullName = $_.FullName -replace "$usershare", 'X:' }
```

The output I need is which is what the users will see in their systems.

```
X:\super\long\directory\path\
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the `$userShare` variable contains characters that have [special meaning in Regular Expressions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcharacters.html) (and `-replace` uses Regex), you need to `[Regex]::Escape()` that string.

First thing to notice is that you start the UNC paths with **three** backslashes, where you should only have **two**.
Next is that your `$results` variable is simply declared as string and should probably be the result of a `Get-ChildItem` command..

I guess what you want to do is something like this:

```
$uncPath   = "\\server\Share$\super\long\directory\path\"    #"# the UNC folder path
$usershare = "\\server\Share$"

$results = Get-ChildItem -Path $uncPath | ForEach-Object {
    $_.FullName -replace ([regex]::Escape($usershare)), 'X:'
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Is there any problem to use < $Results | ForEach-Object { $_.replace("$usershare", 'X:') } > instead, i see this simpler and do the trick ?

Comment: @BahyGhassan .Replace() is case-sensitive. Also, `$_` is a FileInfo or DirectoryInfo object. Not just a string containing the path, so you need the `FullName` property at least.

Comment: @Theo For reference, `DirectoryInfo.ToString` resolves to `FullName` and `FileInfo.ToString` resolves to `Name`.

Comment: @Theo thank you so much for the explanation, Your suggestion solved my issue. and I also understand why I was having the problem.